# Why am I getting "No tests discovered" with Python tests in VS Code?

Tags: python, python-unittest

This is my first few lines of code but I've coded for 20 years so I quickly wanted to get unit testing running.

I am using

- Windows 10
- VS Code 1.30.2 from 7th January, 2019.
- Python 3.7.2
- Python Extension ms-python.python 2018.12.1

Here's the contents of the folder I'm in.

```
    Directory: C:\DATA\Git\Py\my_first_code


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
d-----       19/01/2019     21:42                __pycache__
-a----       19/01/2019     21:35            289 messing.py
-a----       19/01/2019     21:42            204 test_messing.py
-a----       19/01/2019     22:07              0 __init__.py
```

I am not in a "venv", as far as I know.

This is the contents of `test_messing.py`.

```
import unittest

class Test_Math(unittest.TestCase):
    def math_multiply__when__2_times_2__then__equals_4(self):
        self.assertEqual(2 * 2, 4)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

The `__init__.py` is empty, I added it to see if it helps, and `messing.py` contains like a 8 lines of some code from a book.

When I try to discover the tests in VS Code I get.

> No tests discovered, please check the configuration settings for the tests. Source: Python (Extension)

More interestingly, running test discovery via the Python command line looks like this.

```
PS C:\DATA\Git\Py\my_first_code> python -m unittest discover -v -s . -p test_*.py

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 0 tests in 0.000s

OK
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As it says in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#basic-example) for the `unittest` module, Your test method names need to begin with `test`.

> tests are defined with methods whose names start with the letters test. This naming convention informs the test runner about which methods represent tests.

For example

```
class TestMath(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_multiply(self):
        self.assertEqual(2 * 2, 4)

    def test_multiply_negative(self):
        self.assertEqual(-2 * -2, 4)
        self.assertEqual(2 * -2, -4)

    # etc...
```

Note that none of these actually test your `messing.py` functionality. In order to do that you need to `import messing`, call functions on it, and assert the values those functions return are expected.

Finally, a few conventions you should follow:

- Use short, simple test names
- Avoid using double underscores since those often refer to "magic" variables in Python
- Don't refer to what you're testing in every test since the suite itself already refers to it by name
- Your class names should not contain underscores

Comment: Test _methods_ need to start with test..! Even after I read your answer - which has great advice gratefully received, thanks - I edited my code and still got it wrong. Facepalm. I had it the exact other way around, that the class name needed `Test*` and the methods didn't matter.

Comment: OMG, I was pulling my hair out... No tests discovered, again and again. All I needed to do was rename the method to test_*():   .....   :D